# Check if user has role Discord Python

Tags: python, discord

Hello I want to make an discord bot that checks first that the member has the permission to execute the command. Example: With !create you can create random keys but only the role Owner can use !create how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `@commands.has_role("Owner")` when creating the command to limit it to the specified role only

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/ext/commands/api.html?highlight=has_role#discord.ext.commands.has_role

> discord.ext.commands.has_role(item)
>
> A check() that is added that checks if the member invoking the command has the role specified via the name or ID specified.
> If a string is specified, you must give the exact name of the role,
> including caps and spelling.
>
> If an integer is specified, you must give the exact snowflake ID of
> the role.
>
> If the message is invoked in a private message context then the check
> will return False.
>
> This check raises one of two special exceptions, MissingRole if the
> user is missing a role, or NoPrivateMessage if it is used in a private
> message. Both inherit from CheckFailure.
>
> Changed in version 1.1: Raise MissingRole or NoPrivateMessage instead
> of generic CheckFailure
> Parameters
> item (Union[int, str]) – The name or ID of the role to check.

Comment: Welcome, to StackOverflow! When posting links, please also exclude an excerpt of the relevant content in case the site goes down in the future. Thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminSchmidt updated thanks for letting me know!

Answer (score 0):

if you are using [discord.py](https://pypi.org/project/discord.py/), you can check their reference which states that the hook `on_message()` contains a [Message](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message) object, which has an `author` attribute.

That `author` is a [Member](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Member) and can be compared with the attribute `members` of the [Role](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Role) object.

I'm not an expert of this library but a quick read of the documentation made it look an easy task